# python parse bnf grammar and walk

Tags: python, parsing

I have thousand independent bnf grammar strings on hand, and try to figure out the deepest one or a set for some conditions, so I try to look for some python packages to help on this purpose. (e.g. parse bnf grammar and walk through the AST tree generated).
  Does [grako](https://github.com/swayf/grako) help on this?
  Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add a couple examples of the strings and some conditions you are looking for?

Comment: there are the sample BNF grammar strings, the main part of the grammar likes `grammar1 = 'show' { 'foo' | 'bar'} { 'abc' <abc-id> | 'def' <def-id>}` @16num